# How can I set an html element that is hidden but still searchable by the browser?

Tags: html, css, browser

- Use case: a site of cards without the name seen, but that nonetheless would be useful to be able to search by the name

> Imagine album cards without the name of the album, only the image, but that one could `Ctrl`+`F` and search for the album

Is there any specific element for that? Or any `css` rule that could work?

Comment: my answer should work but you can try using visibility css property

Comment: Just replied to @moqiyuanshi, these options work if you can place any element at any place, but if you are within a grid, an extra element can break the distribution, I however think there's no better alternative than these options (?)

Answer (score 2):

Three solutions:

1. set the same color for text and background
2. set opacity to 0
3. set position: fixed and top: 0 or z-index: -1

Comment: All of these solutions wouldn't work out-of-the-box if located for example within a grid, since I'm forced to create an element there that will be counted. Isn't there any better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a style in your `.css` file, and a class on your element like so:

```css
.yourElement {
    z-index: -99999; /* this make sure the element go behind everything */
    opacity: 0; /* reduce opacity */
}
```